# can't style <a> element separately from the list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have a ul:

```
<ul class="myListClass">
    <li><a class="theSelected" href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

the color of the text is applied through styles:

```
.myListClass li a
{
    color: red;
}
```

I want the class `theSelected` to have a different color, but this has no effect on the style:

```
.theSelected 
{
   color: white;
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the selector `.myListClass li a` is [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `.theSelected`.

One option would be to increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of `.theSelected` to something like:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gz2g8hmu/)

```
.myListClass li a.theSelected {
    color: white;
}
```

You could also decrease the specificity of the previous selector too.

---

For what it's worth, here is the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) calculation of each selector:

- `.myListClass li a` - 12
- `.myListClass li a.theSelected` - 22
- `.theSelected` - 10

Here is a [helpful link](http://specificity.keegan.st/) for automatically calculating these values.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest (I'm sure you know this already, Josh), `li a.theSelected`, `.myListClass li .theSelected`, `.myListClass .theSelected`, and `.myListClass a.theSelected` would all work, too.